# facebook login on my website

Tags: html, facebook, forms

All I want to do is add a facebook login and password form on my website for the convenience of my users.

The user will simply type in their fb email and password and hit enter it will redirect them to their facebook feeds. I am not using it as a login or anything, so I don't believe I need to use the api.

http://jsfiddle.net/9fxz2/1/

```
<form method="post" action="hhttps://www.facebook.com/">
<input type="text" class="inputtext" name="email" id="email" value="Email"      tabindex="1">
<input type="password" class="inputtext" name="pass" id="pass" tabindex="2" />
</form>
```

cant get it to work. after you type in your email and pw it should (when it's working) go to their FB FEEDS on Facebook.com/

Comment: "I am not using it as a login or anything"...  oh, really.  Then what do you plan to do with their passwords?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should follow FB prescriptions and tutorials available on FB website for developers.

The roadmap for developer can be useful http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/ but a bit bored.

I advice you to read around Javascript API to understand how it can be possible: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

when you feel ready, create an account developer on FB: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/create-developer-account/

Then you should be able to create FB application which allow you to use FB Login and FB Feeds